# Confusing Javascript statement

Tags: javascript

I saw this javascript code and I don't understand what it does.

```
Url = function() { }

$Url = new Url();
```

Why there is no `var` keyword used ? Is this any kind of object initialization ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without var you are assigning the variable to the scope of a global object (in a browser context `window`), unless the var was defined earlier.

Try this:

```
Url = function() { }
$Url = new Url();
alert(window.$Url)
```

Comment: "Global object" would be more accurate than "global scope".